# Invoke-RestMethod cmdlet not found in Orchestrator 2012 R2 Run .Net Script Activity

Tags: powershell, system-center

I'm trying to use Invoke-RestMethod in a PowerShell script within an Orchestrator 2012 R2 runbook.  When I run the runbook, it tells me:

> The term 'Invoke-RestMethod' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

If I copy and paste the line from the activity to a PowerShell console on the runbook server, it works as expected.  The [documentation for Invoke-RestMethod](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849971(v=wps.620).aspx) tells me that it was introduced in .NET v3.  The [documentation for "Run .Net Script"](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh206103.aspx) says:

> This activity is compatible with .NET CLR version 2.0 and later.

IIRC, .NET 3 was the next one after .NET 2, so I'm assuming this statement means it should support at least .NET 3 PowerShell cmdlets.  Can anyone shed any light on why this isn't working for me?

PS: When I use the Invoke REST Service from the REST Integration Pack, it returns the data with quotes around the returned string, which means I have to put yet another activity after it to strip the quotes off, which is what I'm doing as a workaround.  I'd rather have one extra line in an existing script, rather than have to add two extra activities to accomplish the same thing.

Comment: What is the output for `$PSVersionTable.PSVersion` ?

Comment: Major Minor Build Revision - 4 0 -1 -1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that Orchestrator only uses PowerShell v2 by default. This can be changed with a registry hack:
http://www.scsm.se/?p=1458
I've done this on my server and it works for me.